# Android Adding buttons

Tags: java, android, button, processing

im trying to do android App with GUI to control arduino  using apwidgets library .

now i have 4 buttons side by side .. but i want to add more buttons under each of them.( i mean i want to add button under of RED button and so on .  but idont know this language . can you help me ?

```
//Setup GUI********************************
 buttonWidth=((width/n)-(n*gap));
 buttonHeight=(height/2);
 widgetContainer = new APWidgetContainer(this); //create new container for widgets
 redButton =new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-4)+(gap*1)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "RED"); //Create a RED button
 greenButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-3)+(gap*2)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "GREEN"); //Create a GREEN button
 blueButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-2)+(gap*3)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "BLUE"); //Create a BLUE button
 offButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-1)+(gap*4)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "OFF"); //Create a OFF button
 widgetContainer.addWidget(redButton); //place red button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(greenButton); //place green button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(blueButton);//place blue button in container
 widgetContainer.addWidget(offButton);//place off button in container
 background(0); //Start with a black background
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to use XML for declaring all your layouts (view stuff). [Declaring Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)

Comment: thanks for replies but i use processing ide , and i m doing button using apwidgets library . you think , XML is suitable for Processing android ide . ?

Comment: I have never used it :/ sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: okay guys . i find my own solution .i  looked at the codes of library and i got it how to do .thanks

Comment: Cool. You should submit your solution and accept it for others with your same problem!

Answer (score 0):

it's so easy , i just added a button ,calls yeniButton . begin of the code `APButton redButton, greenButton, blueButton, offButton,yeniButton;`
AN IMPORTANT THING IS new APbutton(int x ,int y, buttons width,buttons heights,"name");
and i defined a new button u can see the following code

```
buttonWidth=((width/n)-(n*gap));
     buttonHeight=(height/2);
     widgetContainer = new APWidgetContainer(this); //create new container for widgets
     yeniButton = new APButton(700,600,(buttonWidth/2),(buttonHeight/2),"Yeni buton");
     redButton =new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-4)+(gap*1)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "RED"); //Create a RED button
     greenButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-3)+(gap*2)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "GREEN"); //Create a GREEN button
     blueButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-2)+(gap*3)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "BLUE"); //Create a BLUE button
     offButton = new APButton((buttonWidth*(n-1)+(gap*4)), gap, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, "OFF"); //Create a OFF button
     widgetContainer.addWidget(redButton); //place red button in container
     widgetContainer.addWidget(greenButton); //place green button in container
     widgetContainer.addWidget(blueButton);//place blue button in container
     widgetContainer.addWidget(offButton);//place off button in container
     widgetContainer.addWidget(yeniButton);
     background(0); //Start with a black background
```